# Parsing of a logical expression and converting it to a tree in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, logic

I have complex logical expression that look like this:

```
((((!((cond1) || (cond2) || (cond3)) && (cond4))) && (cond5)) <= (((cond6) || (cond7) || (cond8)) || (cond9)))
```

Each line has several dozens of expressions. The allowed logical signs are `||`, `&&`, `!` and `<=`. `<=` means leads, as in `a <= b`means that b leads to a.

I need to go over those statements and check the conditions, since some of them are no longer valid. I want to be able to parse it to a tree, then check each of it leafs (where each leaf is a condition), delete the unwanted leafs and build the full and correct expressions back.

I know that each node of the tree is defined by a pair of the first bracket and the bracket that closes it, but I don't know how to identify such pairs and how to identify the logical sign between them.

All signs except for `!` come between two expressions.

Comment: Are these expressions in perl or is it from another language ? Is it for only one shot code cleanup ?

Comment: It's not in Perl, it's a .va file, I'm not sure what language it's. I want to write a Perl script that will parse them.

Comment: ysth is right, you should use a formal grammar to solve your issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like a case for [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse::RecDescent):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parse::RecDescent;

my $text = '((((!((cond1) || (cond2) || (cond3)) && (cond4))) && (cond5)) <= (((cond6) || (cond7) || (cond8)) || (cond9)))';

#$::RD_TRACE=1;

my $grammar = q{

startrule: expr

expr: operand operation(s?)
    { $return = @{$item[2]} ? { 'operations' => $item[2], 'lvalue' => $item[1] } : $item[1] }

operation: /\|\||&&|<=/ operand
    { $return = { 'op' => $item[1], 'rvalue' => $item[2] } }

operand: '(' expr ')'
    { $return = $item[2] }

operand: '!' operand
    { $return = { 'op' => '!', 'value' => $item[2] } }

operand: /\w+/

};

my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new($grammar);
my $result = $parser->startrule($text) or die "Couldn't parse!\n";

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
print Dumper $result;
```

The grammar, in English:

The whole thing is an expression.  An expression is an operand followed by zero or more binary operators and their operands.  Each operand is either a parenthesized expression, '!' followed by an operand, or a word (e.g. `cond1`).

Every node in the produced tree is in one of the following forms:

- `cond1` - a condition
- `{ 'op' => '!', 'value' => 'node' }` - ! applied to another node
- `{ 'lvalue' => 'node', 'operations' => [ one or more of: { 'op' => 'binop', 'rvalue' => 'node' } ] }` - series of one or more operations representing node binop node binop node ...

I didn't break series of binary operations (e.g. `((cond1) || (cond2) || (cond3))`) into a binary tree because you provided no information about precedence or associativity.

Output for your example is:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'lvalue' => {
    'lvalue' => {
      'lvalue' => {
        'op' => '!',
        'value' => {
          'lvalue' => 'cond1',
          'operations' => [
            {
              'op' => '||',
              'rvalue' => 'cond2'
            },
            {
              'op' => '||',
              'rvalue' => 'cond3'
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      'operations' => [
        {
          'op' => '&&',
          'rvalue' => 'cond4'
        }
      ]
    },
    'operations' => [
      {
        'op' => '&&',
        'rvalue' => 'cond5'
      }
    ]
  },
  'operations' => [
    {
      'op' => '<=',
      'rvalue' => {
        'lvalue' => {
          'lvalue' => 'cond6',
          'operations' => [
            {
              'op' => '||',
              'rvalue' => 'cond7'
            },
            {
              'op' => '||',
              'rvalue' => 'cond8'
            }
          ]
        },
        'operations' => [
          {
            'op' => '||',
            'rvalue' => 'cond9'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: You should also consider [Regexp::Grammars](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Grammars), which is the successor to Parse::RecDescent, if you're using Perl 5.10 or higher.

Comment: Could you please explain what it does, and at what format does it return the result. I need to manipulate the data, and I can't understand how to access it.

Comment: @Ilya Melamed: I was hoping it would be self-explanatory, but I added an attempt at explanation.