# Search pattern for decoding logic

Tags: regex, perl, search, logic

I need to decode logic from a database I reference when determining if an attribute is able to be associated with an item I am defining. The database uses standard logic flow and order of importance. I need to be able to determine nested conditional statements in the strings I pull from the database. For example:

```
$val = "(red && (blue || yellow)) && black";
```

The string I'd pull from the database would resemble:

```
$pull = "red.yellow.black";
```

I would separate `$pull` on `.` and store the values in an array, then I'd verify each value is in the array(s) I generate from the `$val` string. I am having trouble with the best method for determining how to unpack the nested logic though. Initially, I considered just using a regex, then removing the portion of the logic that has been assessed like so:

```
($eval) = $val =~ /.*\((.*)?\)/; $val =~ s/(.*)\((.*)?\)(.*)/$1 $2/;
```

If I do this in a `while ($val =~ /\(/)` loop, I could probably stack the extracted logic into arrays and evaluate the logical expression in each element to determine if each condition is true for the item I am evaluating, but there's something wrong with my regexp causing the sequence to fail. The `?` is not as lazy as I thought, apparently...

```
my $val = "(red && (blue || yellow)) && black";
my $pull = "red.yellow.black";
my @stack = ();

until ($val !~ /\(/) {
    my ($eval) = $val =~ /.*\((.*)?\)/;
    push(@stack, $eval);
    print "$eval\n";
    $val =~ s/(.+)\((.*)?\)(.*)/$1 $2/;
    print "$val\n";
}
```

If I just run the sequence in a perl shell, with some debugging info, I get this:

```
[bin]$ perl -e 'my $val = "((red && (blue || yellow) && black)"; my $pull = "red.yellow.black"; my @stack = (); until ($val !~ /\(/) { my ($eval) = $val =~ /.*\((.+)?\).?/; push(@stack, $eval); print "EVAL: $eval\n";$pause = <STDIN>;$val =~ s/(.*)\((.*)?\)(.*)/$1 $2/;print "VAL: $val\n"; }'
EVAL: blue || yellow) && black

VAL: ((red &&  blue || yellow) && black
EVAL: red &&  blue || yellow

VAL: ( red &&  blue || yellow
EVAL:
```

Any input on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated, and any improvements on efficiency would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Update: Ok, so I just dumbed the whole thing down like this. I lose some of the order of operations, but if I evaluate each statement individually, whenever one of the conditions is broken, I'll pick it up and be able to act on the info accordingly. The code I am going to expand on is below. This would just return the individual components of the expression. I don't like how everything ouside parenthesis is concatenated into the first element, but I guess it still works fundamentally.

```
my $val = "(red && (blue || yellow)) && black";
$val =~ s/\s+//g;

my @chars = ();
my @ops = ();

while ($val) {
    my ($char) = $val =~ /(.)/;
    $val =~ s/.//;
    push @chars, $char;
}

my $index = 0;
foreach my $char (@chars) {
    if ($char =~ /\(/) {
        $index++;
    } elsif ($char =~ /\)/) {
        $index--
    }
    #assign the character to the index.
    $ops[$index] .= $char;
}

s/[()]//g for @ops;
print " @ops\n";
```

Output:

```
[/bin]$ perl decode_logic.pl
 &&black red&& blue||yellow
```

Comment: The brackets are unbalanced in `$val` --  `(((` agains `))`.

Comment: I'm afraid that a simple regex may not cut it, if I understand your need (to parse that and+or statement).  See for instance [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4518235/4653379), where they've written a (simple) grammar for a seemingly very similar task. There are also modules out there to "parse tree"s.  In case I don't get it and the job's in fact much simpler, you could still make use of [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html), for those nested parens.

Comment: Thanks @PolarBear. I fixed the inequity.